# Python: Request handler in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Flask, and the request handling seems to be like:

```
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

So I end up defining the functions for all my routes in a single file. I'd much rather have functions for a model in its own file, e.g. get_user, create_user in user.py. I've used Express (node.js) in the past, and I can do:

```
user = require('./models/user')
app.get('/user', user.list)
```

where user.coffee (or .js) has a list function.

How do I do the same in Flask?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.route):

> A decorator that is used to register a view function for a given URL rule. This does the same thing as [add_url_rule()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.add_url_rule) but is intended for decorator usage

The `add_url_rule` docs elaborate:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    pass
```

Is equivalent to the following:

```
def index():
    pass
app.add_url_rule('/', 'index', index)
```

You can just as easily import your view functions into a `urls.py` file and call `add_url_rule` once for each view function there instead of defining the rules along side the functions or use the [lazy loading pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/lazyloading/).